# how to get nested JSON array without using foreign key relationship in models using sequelizejs orm?

Tags: sequelize.js

i am using using sequelize orm tool for my application ,i need to get nested JSON array using models,but models are not having foreign Key relationship,below are tables

```
table 1:
        user
        -----   
        user_id  user_name region_id
            1       user1   201
            2       user2   202
            3       user3   202
            4       user4   201     

table2:     
        region
        -------     
        region_id  region_name
            201     region1
            202     region2
            203     region3
```

it has one to many relation,please anyone tell me how to code in sequelizejs and below given expected JSON array

```
{
    "user_details": [
    {
        "user_name": "user1",
        "user_id": 1,
        "region_id": 201,
        "region_details": {
            "region_id": 201,
            "region_name": "region1"
        }
    }, {
        "user_name": "user2",
        "user_id": 2,
        "region_id": 201,
        "region_details": {
            "region_id": 201,
            "region_name": "region1"
        }
    },{
        "user_name": "user3",
        "user_id": 3,
        "region_id": 202,
        "region_details": {
            "region_id": 202,
            "region_name": "region2"
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: any reason why you are not using relationship ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding a foreign key reference without a constraint. See the docs

[see link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#enforcing-a-foreign-key-reference-without-constraints)